# How to validate an updated has-many-through collection

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am try to figure out **how to properly validate a model collection whenever that collection is updated using the << collection operator.**
In our legacy app (Rails 3.2.1), I found that **platform_collection_obj.platforms** is updated using **<<** operator

**Example**:

```
collection.platforms << new_platform
```

In researching how to validate that each **platform in platforms collection** has appropriate data, I found that I should use custom-validation function. So I tried adding **each_platform_branch_id** validation function to **PlatformCollections** Model.  However, I found in testing (via rails console) that the validation was not triggered.

In reading [Has-Many-Association-Collection Info](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many), I came across this

> Adds one or more objects to the collection by setting their foreign keys to the collection's primary key. Note that this operation instantly fires update SQL without waiting for the save or update call on the parent object, unless the parent object is a new record. This will also run validations and callbacks of associated object(s).

This excerpt indicates that using **<<** to perform update on collection.platforms will not trigger the parent validations, which in this case would be the **PlatformCollection:each_platform_branch_id** validation function.  I know that manually perforning **collection.save** would trigger validation, but it would be too late b/c **<<** has already updated the DB.

So to restate the question is:
**How do I properly validate a has-many-through-model collection whenever that collection is updated using the << collection operator?**

**PlatformCollections Model**

```
class PlatformCollection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tezt
  has_many :platform_collection_platforms, :order => "platform_collection_platforms.default DESC"
  has_many :platforms, :through => :platform_collection_platforms, :order => "platform_collection_platforms.default DESC"

  def each_platform_branch_id
    platforms.each do |p|
      if p.branch_id != @branch.id
        err_msg = "Invalid Platform: #{p.to_json} for PlatformCollection: #{self.to_json}. " \
                  "Expected Branch: #{@branch.id}, Actual Branch: #{p.branch_id}"
        errors.add(:platform, err_msg)
      end
    end
  end
```

**Platforms Model**

```
class Platform < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  belongs_to :branch
  has_many :platform_collection_platforms
  has_many :platform_collections, :through => :platform_collection_platforms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [association callbacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-callbacks) to perform checks or call methods before or after an object was added to (or removed from) an association. For example, like this:

```
has_many :platforms, through:    :platform_collection_platforms,
                     before_add: :check_branch_id

private

def check_branch_id(platform)
  throw(:abort) if platform.branch_id != branch_id
end
```

Btw. Ruby on Rails 3.2.1 was released more than 11 years ago, reach end-of-life about 7 years ago and has a [long list of well-known security vulnerabilities](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-12043/product_id-22569/version_id-414975/Rubyonrails-Rails-3.2.1.html). I highly recommend updating that application to a more up-to-date and more secure version.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `<<` operator at all here (`collection.platforms << new_platform`), perhaps it would be best to explicitly create the JOIN record?

i.e. Something along the lines of:

```
collection.platform_collection_platforms.build(
  platform_collection: collection,
  platform: new_platform
)
```

(My goodness, that's a confusing set of names!!)

Now you're in complete control what to `validate`.